# Tailwindcss add custom aspect-ratio class

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I try actually to add tailwind custom properties for aspect-ratio like that:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      aspectRatio: {
        '4/3': '4 / 3',
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I have followed the instructions on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio#basic-usage
and also tried to add an arbitrary class like that:

```
aspect-[2/3]
```

but the classes are not generated or considered on the output css file

for info other classes for example colors and custom text fonts are generated.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: What Tailwind version do you use? `aspect-ratio` was [introduced](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-alpha1---2021-10-01) in Tailwind 3.0

Comment: Ok! I see that I am using the version 2.2.9 of Tailwind !
It seems that it's not compatible, I think that I should add it as a custom css property...

Comment: Just create new utility [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities) like I've done it [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SwA5mjOUtl?file=config) for Tailwind v2 - it should work (JIT included)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka: do you know how can I ket the new utility plugin responsive ?

Comment: Same way as any other utility - like `sm:my-aspect-5/1` etc

Comment: Already tried, that unfortunately don't work